# How Do I Get Google to Show Different Sections as Parts of the Same Site?

Tags: html

Searching for NFL.com on Google shows www.nfl.com, but it also shows nfl.com/teams, nfl.com/schedules, etc... as different sections of the same website. Is there a way that I can tell Google how my website is organized?

Right now if I search Google for my 3 page website it will show 3 different results, instead of a single result with 3 sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot tell Google to do this - Google generates these links automatically.

For more information sign up for or see https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools and from the left hand menu for your site look for: Site Configuration > Sitelinks for a detailed explanation.